# PHP - Count items per hour

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array like this..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => 1
            [hour] => 04
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item] => 5
            [hour] => 04
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item] => 1
            [hour] => 09
        )
)
```

I am trying to create a new array so I can track how many items are purchased in which hour and spot hourly trends.

I think I need to end up with an array that looks like this

```
Array
(
    [item1] => Array
        (
            [hour04] => 1
            [hour09] => 1
        )

    [item5] => Array
        (
            [hour04] => 1
        )
)
```

Is this the correct approach, or is there a better way to represent the final data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is all info you want to store in the array it is totally enough to use this:

```
Array
(
     [1] => Array ( //item 1
        (
             [4] => 1  //hour 4 has one item of item 1
             [9] => 1 
        )
     [5] => Array ( //item 5
        (
             [4] => 1
        )
)
```

then you have stored this in `$itemsPerHour` you can access it `$itemsPerHour[$itemId][3];` to get how many items of `$itemId` were sold at hour 3.